# How do you build a local package before it is installed elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am building a local package in one directory (lib), and locally installing it from another directory (app). Both projects are typescript.

I've figured out how to do this, but since I am using typescript, it would be very convenient to compile the library when I run `npm install -D ../lib` from inside `app`. Is there a way of doing this? I defined a `preinstall` script in the library, but it doesn't run unless I run `install` in `lib`.

Using that knowledge, I could create a `preinstall` in `app` that would go into `lib` and build it, but that doesn't sit right with me. Is there an alternative? A part of the lifecycle that runs when somebody else is installing the current project?

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you can use `install` script. It'll excecute when installing the package. This works fine for me.